# Book series about an Australian adventurer with a metal arm

Tags: story-identification, books

About 10 years back, I read a series of books about an Australian adventurer (ex-military Special Forces type of guy).

- The protagonist has a metal arm (he loses the arm in the first book I think).
- He has a scientist/genius-type friend nicknamed Wizard who builds a metal arm for him
- In one of the books, the villain is his father (who is in the American military, very high ranking post).
- He also has a daughter (around 10 years old I think) who is a major part of the adventures.
- He is kind of Indiana Jones (who is mentioned by the protagonist in the book once or twice) as far as the type of adventures are concerned.

However, I don't remember the name of the protagonist or the author or any of the book titles. Thus, I am not able to find by searching any of these details on Google or something.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the [Huntsman series](https://matthewreilly.fandom.com/wiki/Huntsman_Series) (launched in 2005) by Matthew Reilly. The books are a military adventure set in the modern day, but with some ancient prophecies and powers to set the plot going.

The main character is Jack West Jr, an ex-Australian SAS soldier. He lost his arm reaching through a stream of lava, and was built a new one by Max 'Wizard' Epper, who was also known by 'Merlin'.

Jack's adopted daughter is Lily. She turns out to be one of the Oracles of Siwa.

There are six novels and a short story in the series. Jack lost his arm in the first book, "Seven Ancient Wonders".